# Python, how can I rename several files based off a list?

Tags: python, windows, list, rename

Using python with Windows Im trying to rename several files at once that are in the same folder but I cant use a list to do a rename that is why I get this error when I try my code:

> os.rename(dirlist[1], words[1]) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Here is the sample code:

```
import os
import sys
words = os.listdir('C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test')
dirlist = os.listdir('C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test')

words = [w.replace('E', 'e') for w in words]
print words 

os.rename(dirlist[1], words[1])
```

What I am trying to achieve is have my python script ran on a folder of choice and the script will take all the files in there and will rename all of them. But the tricky part comes when I cant single out the folder names and have them renamed because they are attached to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.listdir` is only giving you back the basename results. Not full path. They don't exist in your current working directory. You would need to join them back with the root:

```
root = 'C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test'
for item in os.listdir(root):
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, item)
    os.rename(fullpath, fullpath.replace('E', 'e'))
```

**Update**

In response to your comment about how to perform larger number of replacements, I had suggested you could use `translate` and `maketrans`.

Let's start with our dict and a source string:

```
d = {'E': 'e', 'a': 'B', 'v': 'C'}
s = 'aAaAvVvVeEeE'
```

First, let me show you an example of a very primitive and entry level approach:

```
for old, new in d.iteritems():
    s = s.replace(old, new)

print s
# BABACVCVeeee
```

That example loops over your dictionary, calling the replacement multiple times. It works, and it makes perfect sense,  using simple syntax. But it kind of sucks having to loop over the dictionary for every string and call replace multiple times.

There are many other ways to do this I am sure, but another approach is to create a translation table once, and then reuse it for every string:

```
import string

old, new = zip(*d.items())
print old, new
# ('a', 'E', 'v') ('B', 'e', 'C')

old_str, new_str = ''.join(old), ''.join(new)
print old_str, new_str
# aEv BeC

table = string.maketrans(old_str, new_str)

print s.translate(table)
# BABACVCVeeee
```

That will split the dictionary out to key and value tuples. Then we join then intro strings and pass them to `maketrans`, which will give us back a table. We only have to do that once. Now we have a table and can use it to translate any string.

Comment: Glad to help. Saves you from doing two listdir's as well :-)

Comment: I am curious though would there be a way to substitute "('E', 'e')" with an entire dictionary like:                                     d = {
'a':'B',
'v':'C'
}

Comment: Look at "maketrans" [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) or you can do it in a for loop over the dict if you want a more primive entry level approach

Comment: Im not sure how maketrans could help I did alot of reading on it. using your code im trying do like 7 variable changes similar to the "('E', 'e')" example but I would like to be able to list all of the changes I need made as a string so like d = { 'a':'B', 'v':'C' } and then just put d into your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because your current working directory doesn't points to `'C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test'`, by default it points to `c:\python27` if you're using  python 2.7, you can check yours by `os.getcwd()`, so you should change your current working directory to `'C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test'` before applying that rename.

use `os.chdir()` to change the current working directory.

```
import os
import sys
words = os.listdir('C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test')
dirlist = os.listdir('C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test')

words = [w.replace('E', 'e') for w in words]
print words 

os.chdir('C:/Users/Any/Desktop/test')  #this changes the current working directory
os.rename(dirlist[1], words[1])
```

Comment: Out of curiosity...you didn't downvote me and then post a very similar answer much after me did you? Not accusing..just asking.

Comment: @jdi why would I downvote you? I suggested him to use `os.chdir()` which is not similar to your answer or is it?

Comment: Hah. I was just asking, because the downvote made no sense on my answer. And you added something after mine was accepted. Thought maybe you hated me :-) No yours is a different angle for sure.

Comment: +1 - For being a good person and providing good competition :-)