# Python: Replace one list with another list?

Tags: python, list, rename

I'm stuck. I'm moving folders around on our network which all have a unique ID into a central location. There are a few folders with typos and therefore do not match a unique ID in the central location. I have found the correct IDS but I need to rename these folders before I move them.  For example, I have created an excel spreadsheet with the wrong unique ID and in a separate column have the correct ID. Now, I want to rename the folders with the correct ID and then transfer those folders to the central location. My code is....rough because I can't think of a good way to do it. I feel like using a list is the way to go, but since my code is iterating through a folder I'm not sure how to achieve this

**Edit: I think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916625/python-how-can-i-rename-several-files-based-off-a-list?rq=1) may be what I'm looking for**

Ex: 
In Folder A : A file named 12334 SHOULD be renamed 1234. Then moved to the base directory with in folder 1234.

Heres my code:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import traceback
import collections
import shutil

movdir = r"C:\Scans"
basedir = r"C:\Links"
subfolder = "\Private Drain Connections"

try:
    #Walk through all files in the directory that contains the files to copy
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(movdir):
        for filename in files:
            #find the name location and name of files
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            #file name and extension
            ARN, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            print ARN

            #Location of the corresponding folder in the new directory
            link = os.path.join(basedir, ARN)
            if not os.path.exists(link):
                newname = re.sub(372911000002001,372911000003100,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372809000001400,372909000001400,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372809000001500,372909000001500,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372809000001700,372909000001700,ARN)
                newname = re.sub(372812000006800,372912000006800,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000006900,372912000006900,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007000,372912000007000,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007100,372912000007100,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007200,372912000007200,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007300,372912000007300,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007400,372912000007400,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007500,372912000007500,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007600,372912000007600,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000007700,372912000007700,ARN)
                newname =re.sub(372812000011100,372912000011100,ARN)


                os.rename(os.path.join(movdir, ARN, extension ),
                os.path.join(movdir, newname, extension))
                oldpath = os.path.join(root, newname)
                print ARN, "to", newname
                newpath = basedir + "\\" + newname + subfolder
                shutil.copy(oldpath, newpath)
                print "Copied"

except:
    print ("Error occurred")
```

Thanks to the answers below here is my final code:

```
import arcpy
import os
import re
import sys
import traceback
import collections
import shutil

movdir = r"C:\Scans"
basedir = r"C:\Links"
subfolder = "\Private Drain Connections"


import string

l = ['372911000002001',
'372809000001400',
'372809000001500',
'372809000001700',
'37292200000800'
]
l2 = ['372911000003100',
'372909000001400',
'372909000001500',
'372909000001700',
'372922000000800'
]

try:
    #Walk through all files in the directory that contains the files to copy
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(movdir):
        for filename in files:
            #find the name location and name of files
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            #file name and extension
            ARN, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            oldname = str(ARN)
            #Location of the corresponding folder in the new directory
            link = os.path.join(basedir, ARN)

            if not os.path.exists(link):
                for ii, jj in zip(l, l2):
                    newname = re.sub(ii,jj, ARN)
                    newname = str(newname)
                    print path
                    newpath = os.path.join(root, oldname) +  extension
                    print "new name", newpath
                    os.rename(path, newpath)
                    print "Renaming"
                    newpath2 = basedir + "\\" + newname + subfolder
                    shutil.copy(newpath, newpath2)
                    print "Copied"
                if newname != ARN:
                    break


            else:
                continue

except:
    print ("Error occurred")
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
        str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "GP ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2 )+ "\n"
    print (pymsg)
    print (msgs)
```

Comment: That's... quite a bit more than just replacing a list...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have the other part of the code down and working , I just need a more efficient way of replacing the bad names.

Comment: Efficient or elegant? How many wrong folders are we talking about?

Comment: @Jblasco there's only 30 currently

Comment: Then I don't think efficiency will be an issue... Elegance takes precedence in my opinion ;)

Comment: @Jblasco Yeah, I'm just trying to future-proof it because I KNOW it will happen again. And I like learning new things! :)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the way to go is to read both lists into list objects:

```
list1 = ["372911000002001", "372809000001400", "372809000001500"]
list2 = ["372911000003100", "372909000001400", "372909000001500"]
for ii, jj in zip(list1, list2):
    newname = re.sub(ii,jj,ARN)  #re.sub returns ARN if no substitution done
    if newname != ARN:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea: try to convert the id's to strings. I mean:

```
            newname = re.sub('372911000002001','372911000003100',ARN)
```

Hope it helps!